# Transform Seq[A] to Map[Int, Seq[A]]

Tags: scala, transformation

How can I transform a Seq[A] to a Map[Int, Seq[A]] in Scala where the value of Int is a param of A (in a functional way) ?

Example:

```
val futures: Seq[Future[Seq[A]]] = ???
val gathered = Future.collect(futures)
gathered.map {
    res => {
       val myseq:Seq[A] = res.flatten
       myseq.map(a => (a.param, a)).toMap
    }
}
```

the resulting value would be Map[Int, A]. Instead I'd like to have a sequence of all A having the same Int param (Map[Int, Seq[A])

Comment: The question is very much unclear. You wish to convert `Seq(1,2,3)` to Map of `(1-> ??)..` ?

Comment: val myseq = Seq((1, 2), (1, 3), (3,4))
expected: Map(1-> Seq(2, 3), 3 -> Seq(4))

Comment: @sonix please update your question because it sounded like you wanted to take some type `A` and use a member function/value of it to group your sequence into a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to prove to the compiler that there is a parameter of type `A` that can be had which satisfies your condition:

```
trait Param[A]{
  def extract(that: A): Int
}

def seqToMap[A](seq: Seq[A])(implicit proof: Param[A]) = 
  seq groupBy (proof.extract)
```

Other than that, you could use structural types (which involve reflection and thus are really inadvisable for performance reasons.)

Comment: Can you tell more on the last line? Using structural types here. Quick example would help :)

Comment: why are the trait and implicit even required? are you assuming `A` is a type parameter?

Comment: @erikallik because without a real type, A is ambiguous. You can not prove A has a method .param without something.